# Amplify Studio can not show table with more than 5MB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

We are building a flutter app with an aws Amplify backend. We use authentication, datastore and graphql api.

Amplify Studio can not fetch more than 5MB of data from the backend dynamodb table. As soon as the table grows bigger than 5MB the content shows empty (but everything is there in dynamodb).

I read that there is an appsync limit that limits Amplify Studio of fetching more than 5MB, but I can not find that information again. Problem is that our app content people can not see their own content and thus not work properly with Amplify Studio.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

We are very well aware that datastore has some limits and you have to manually increase them if necessary. But this is not about datastore, but just the content appearing in Amplify Studio. We will need the tables to be bigger than 5MB.

Comment: You're going to need to paginate and bring back the data in smaller chunks.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that is what I do on the app when I want to get the whole table. But as Amplify Studio is provided by AWS, I don't have direct control over the way it fetches the data. Is there some function or configuration in AWS where I can set the pagination for amplify studio?

Comment: Sounds like the flutter and graphql parts of this question are not relevant?

Comment: It is a backend for a flutter application, but as the title says, it is about Amplify Studio.